# What naming do you use to avoid "stuttering" in Vuex modules?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I've been having a hard time avoiding "stuttering" in Vuex modules. It just seems that most of the time, the module's name is also what it contains.

For example, suppose a module that handles users. I name the module file `user.js`

```js
export default {
  state: {
    users: []
  },
  // mutations and actions for reading, creating, updating users...
}
```

Then in my store's `index.js`

```js
import user from 'user';

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    user
  }
});
```

When I want to get the list of users from a component I have to use:

```
this.$store.user.users
```

If I didn't use a module for the user list, I would just have had `this.$store.users`, which is much more readable and elegant.

Any idea for a naming convention or design pattern that would avoid this stutter?

Comment: Get creative. What's the purpose of having users? Likely, it's access control. So name the module `acl` (industry adopted acronym for Access Control List - a.k.a "user rights and permissions list"). Or you could rename your `users` to `admins` and `regulars`. Or name the lot `list`. All of that aside, your question has little to do with coding and is highly subjective (opinionated). What might seem like a good naming convention to me might not seem the same to you or others. Hence, it's off-topic here.

Comment: How about using `mapState`?

Comment: Maybe put some context on the final part of the name. e.g. `this.$store.user.all`, or if they aren't all users use a name that describes their significance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper).

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex'


export default {
  // ...
  computed: mapState({
    users: state => state.user.users
  })
  // ...
}
```

Then you can use `this.users` as an alias to `this.$store.user.users`

Comment: Although it's a fairly decent solution, ***a)*** it doesn't really solve the problem (you still stutter in `mapState`) and ***b)*** it answers an off-topic question. Which, arguably, is not useful and creates clutter. Chances are the question will be closed as off-topic and removed from the site which, among others, will revert any rep gain you might have had here. In theory, you should avoid answering [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) questions and channel efforts into answering better questions, with higher chances of helping future users. Please read [answer].

Comment: Thanks, that's a helpful way to fix it. As @tao said, it doesn't completely avoid stuttering, but at least my components won't be littered with deeply nested accesses to the store modules. I'll take this for now.

Comment: @LodeRunner mapState supports namespaces, see https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#binding-helpers-with-namespace . It's likely `mapState('user', ['users'])`.

Comment: Actually, it can be even shorter: if `users` is the only state in your store named like that, it could be `...mapState(['users'])`.